# ADFS and .NET Core

Tags: c#, amazon-ec2, .net-core, adfs

I'm trying to implement ADFS for a .NET Core 2 application. Finding that there are very limited documentation regarding the subject.

I'm trying to do this for an application that is located on a EC2 instance in AWS, and trying to reach a ADFS 2.0 server on-prem within our company.

I have managed to solve this issue with an old .NET 4.5 application following this guide: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/identity/ad-fs/deployment/set-up-the-lab-environment-for-ad-fs-in-windows-server-2012-r2#BKMK_15

But I havn't found anything similar for .NET Core applications.
Does anyone have an example or have managed to get this to work with .NET Core?

Answer (score 1):

This is covered for .NET Core 3.1 [here](https://medium.com/the-new-control-plane/authenticating-to-active-directory-federation-services-adfs-2019-with-net-core-3-1-b0bf012fc183).